# No se puede recuperar el siguiente objeto: el iterador alcanzó el final

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive

Al correr un script de Google que tengo para enviar correos, últimamente me ha salido un error, quiero ver si alguno sabe el motivo y como eliminarlo:

[image: No se puede recuperar el siguiente objeto: el iterador alcanzó el final.]

Aparece cuando llega a la línea donde hace el attachment del archivo:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(usuario,email_title,'msg',{htmlBody : htmlbody2,
                                                inlineImages: {
                                                  Logo: LogoBlob,
                                                  fase: fase1Blob,
                                                  Pie2: PieBlob2},
                                             attachments: [archive.next()]});
```

Comment: Bienvenido :) Este sitio tiene normas particulares, por ejemplo, las publicaciones no deben incluir saludos. Más detalles en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase FileIterator tiene efectivamente el método `next()`
pero tienes que considerar que el método se usa para
obtener ***el siguiente*** elemento en **la colección** de archivos o carpetas.(`files = DriveApp.getFiles();`)
lo que indica que de conformidad con la ayuda oficial, este se debe usar con el método `hasNext()` , pues este determina si la llamada `next()` devolverá un elemento.

El  ejemplo clásico es:

```
var files = DriveApp.getFiles();//colección de archivos
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log(file.getName());
}
```

Por lo que debes revisar si en el código faltante o que *no* muestras están alguna de las lineas que se ven en el ejemplo de uso y en su caso incorpora lo faltante.

Te dejo el enlace de la [Clase FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)

Comment: Bienvenido :) Este sitio tiene normas particulares, por ejemplo, las publicaciones no deben incluir saludos. Más detalles en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: Con tu comentario ha quedado resuelto, me ha funcionado perfectamente, eliminé el error de inmediato.

Comment: var archive =   DriveApp.getFilesByName(namearchive);
            var attachments = [];
            while (archive.hasNext()) {
               attachments.push(archive.next());
            };


            MailApp.sendEmail(mail,titulo,mensaje,{cc: mail2,
                                         htmlBody : htmlbody,
                                         attachments: attachments});