# Enviar spreadsheets como archivo adjunto con google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-drive

Soy nuevo en Google Apps Scripts y requiero adjuntar el archivo spreadsheets y enviarlo por correo. He visto como realizar el envió y se envía el email con el archivo adjunto, pero en formato pdf y lo requiero en su formato original `xls` o `xlsx`. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
function enviarEmail(){
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id del archivo);
var destino = 'email de destino';
var asunto = 'Archivo XXXXX ';
var msg = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx'
GmailApp.sendEmail(destino,asunto,msg,{attachments:[file]}); 
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Te sugiero seguir el [tour] (ganarás una medalla). Aunque tu pregunta está mucho mejor que muchas de personas que publican la primera vez te podría ser útil también leer [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Puedes especificar el formato en el que se enviará tu attachment de la siguiente forma

```
// Send an email with a file from Google Drive attached as a PDF.
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
GmailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached file.', {
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
});
```

En tu caso en lugar de `file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)` intenta con  `file.getAs(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL)`

Referencias

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type

Relacionado

- [No se puede recuperar el siguiente objeto: el iterador alcanzó el final](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/213807/65)

Answer (score 1):

Gracias por responder Rubén, al usar file.getAs(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL) me decía que no es posible realizar la conversión una solución que encontré es la siguiente:
// convierte archivo en xlsx y envía adjunto
`function Enviar_xlsx() { var name = "Nombre del archivo"; var sheetId = "Id del archivo google spreadsheets"; var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + sheetId + "/export?format=xlsx&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(); var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().setName(name + ".xlsx"); GmailApp.sendEmail('Email destino', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached  file.', {attachments: [blob]}); }`